# Block free email domains from the contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to block the general email id account from the contact form 7. I have added below code in the function.php file but it is not working.

I am using wordpress 4.6.1, contact form 7 Version 4.6 and twentysixteen theme. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
function blocked_email_domain($email) {
$blocked = array("@gmail.com", "@hotmail.com", "@yahoo.com", "@yahoo.in","@msn.com", "@live.com", "@outlook.com", "@microsoft.com", "@zoho.com", "@rediff.com");
$email = strstr($email, '@');
if(in_array($email, $blocked))
    return false;
else
    return true;
}

    function custom_email_validation_filter($result, $tag) {
    $type = $tag['type'];
    $name = $tag['name'];
    if($name == 'your-email') { // Only apply to fields with the form field name of "your-email"
    $the_value = $_POST[$name];
    if(!blocked_email_domain($the_value)){
    $result['valid'] = false;
    $result->invalidate( $tag, 'You need to provide an email address that isn\'t hosted by a free provider.<br />Please contact us directly if this isn\'t possible.');

    };
    };
    return $result;
    }
    add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email','custom_email_validation_filter', 10, 2); // Email field
    add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_validation_filter', 10, 2); // Required Email field
```

Comment: It is working fine After removing this line  "$result['valid'] = false;"